# problems with minio tenant creation

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner, minio

I am having problems with minio tenant creation, i keep getting:
 `Users creation failed: Put "http://minio.minio-operator.svc.cluster.local/minio/admin/v3/add-user?accessKey=<access_key>": dial tcp <pod_ip>:80: connect: connection refused.`

I am running minio operator on a kubernetes cluster and i am using directpv

i am trying to create a minio tenant for storing cache data for gitlab runners, i managed to deploy minio operator and connect to the web console but tenant creation keeps failing